# Any possible method to clear recycler items offset?

Tags: android

Im trying to use `addItemDecoration(item)` for RecyclerView. And for drawable item i has offset which one calculate from padding.

```kotlin
    override fun getItemOffsets(
        outRect: Rect,
        view: View,
        parent: RecyclerView,
        state: RecyclerView.State
    ) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)
        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == state.itemCount - 1) {
            outRect.setEmpty()
        } else {
            outRect.set(0, 0, drawable!!.intrinsicWidth + paddingLeftPx + paddingRightPx, 0)
          //outRect.set(0, 0, 0, 0) all works properly with that
        }
    }
```

for some reasons drawable does not apply correctly. it happens when im refreshing layout, and distance between 2 items always increments. sometimes drawable has padding more than i give it. but if i put in `outRect.set` method all zeros, all works properly. but im need to use padding for correct design.

this is how it need to look
[image: pic1]

this is how it looks now
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some boolean value (isFirstSetup for example) and check this before calling addItemDecoration. And when you first trigger addItemDecoration - set this boolean to false.

Comment: this is will not work, because sometimes this bug happens with first initialization

Comment: @Spectator share some code where you initialize and update your recyclerView and items in adapter

Comment: why. its not gonna help. the problem in other place. in outRect.set method directly